Error: `callbackHandler` may not be null when connecting to HDFS using Kerberos in Jakarta EE
I am trying to connect to HDFS using Kerberos authentication in a JakartaEE application. The connection code appears to be set up correctly, but I am encountering the following error when attempting to load a file list from HDFS:
14:41:17,006 ERROR [com.hdfs.HdfsFileBrowserBean] (default task-1) Failed to load file list for path: /: java.io.IOException: DestHost:destPort java.ecc.com:8020, LocalHost:localPort localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:0. Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'callbackHandler' may not be null

This suggests that there is an issue with the callbackHandler. I have verified the keytab and principal details but am unsure how to resolve this specific error.
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
setClusterConfig(conf, peerCrawler.getClusterConfig(url, username, password, "hdfs-site"));
setClusterConfig(conf, peerCrawler.getClusterConfig(url, username, password, "core-site"));

String keytabPath = "/opt/wildfly-34.0.0.Final/keytabs/yarn.service.keytab"; 
String principal = "yarn/java.ecc.com@ECC.COM"; 
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration hadoopConfig = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
hadoopConfig.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(hadoopConfig);
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(principal, keytabPath);

String currentUser = UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser().getUserName();
logger.info("Login successful with principal: " + currentUser);

// Get FileSystem instance
this.fileSystem = FileSystem.get(new URI(hdfsUri), conf);

Could anyone help me understand why I'm receiving this error and how to resolve it? Any insights on the callbackHandler parameter would be greatly appreciated.

damm, the problem lies in the CDI, and another part of the code has interrupted the connection with the IPC client.
